# Find Next is only working on the first iteration

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I have an issue regarding my find next, is most probably that I am writing the code wrongly. So if I have the number 810(which is f), find the address, again 810find the address of the 810 other location and so on...

Then I have the first two working fine. So when findnext for the first time it works the way I want, pasting to the last cell, but the other ones do not work. So When I find next for the second time, it does not copy and paste anymore. Any idea how I can fix it?

```
With RgnScenarioScenario

    Set f = .Find(What:=f, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    WsScenarios.Activate
    f.Select
    q = f.Address
    Set x = Range("A:A").FindNext(f)
    x.Select
    z = x.Address
    Set m = Range("A:A").FindNext(f)
    m.Select
    n = m.Address
    Set k = Range("A:A").FindNext(f)
    k.Select
    w = k.Address
    Set a = Range("A:A").FindNext(f)
    a.Select
    g = a.Address

    If q <> z Then

    Range(z).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, ScenarioLastColumn - 6)).Copy

    WsOutput.Activate
    WsOutput.Cells(lLastRow, Columnf).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Else

    End If

    If z <> n Then

    Range(n).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, ScenarioLastColumn - 6)).Copy

    WsOutput.Activate
    WsOutput.Cells(lLastRow, Columnf).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Else

    End If

    If n <> w Then

    Range(n).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, ScenarioLastColumn - 5)).Copy

    WsOutput.Activate
    WsOutput.Cells(lLastRow, Columnf).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Else

    End If

    If w <> g Then

    Range(n).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, ScenarioLastColumn - 5)).Copy

    WsOutput.Activate
    WsOutput.Cells(lLastRow, Columnf).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Else

    End If

    End With
    Next f
```

What my code is looking for is range value of Scenario ID, in this case 810. as you can see in the first print screen I have 3 times 810. in the below just identify 2. This is the issue, it should identify as many as it has. I am struggling at this piece. I tried Autofilter but did not solve my issue. It is all about the Action ID. Has 3, so, my code should bring the 3

Comment: why you have NEXT f in the end of your code? have you a missing code before WITH?

Comment: and look at Set f = .Find(What:=f, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole), f is your value (f=1018) and it is a range in the same time?

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, then declare every variable with a specific type (e.g. `Dim f As Range`), and then come back to [edit] this question once your code compiles again. `Next f` seems to indicate that `f` is a loop counter (an `Integer`? a `Long`?), i.e. you have a `For f = ? To ?` somewhere before the `With` block, yet you're turning `f` into a `Range` in the first line of that `With` block, i.e. the code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: So the second time, your f is a range, and you are looking for a range in ".Find(What:=f". So it will never be found. That is why your code found 1018 only one time

Comment: no. it finds all the times, i am searching the value of a range. Is hard to address my issue. I will try to add an image to maybe look better

Comment: So, just added it. take a look. What my code is looking for is range value of Scenario ID, in this case 810. as you can see in the first print screen I have 3 times 810. in the below just identify 2. This is the issue, it should identify as many as it has. I am struggling at this piece. I tried Autofilter but did not solve my issue. It is all about the Action ID. Has 3, so, my code should bring the 3

Comment: You probably need to add an 'after' component to the find functions otherwise it will start at the top each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attached is a 'FindAll' function which you may be able to use instead?

```
Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That is what I need! Thank you very very much. I am not good and dont know all the possibilities. =)